# Python & CTypes Null Pointer Error

Tags: python, c++, struct, ctypes

I am accessing a C++ shared library from Python. The C++ shared library manages a signal analyzer and is distributed without the source.

One of the functions requires a struct to be passed into the function call and I am not sure I am doing it correctly using ctypes.

The definition for the struct in the header file is:

```
typedef struct saIQPacket {
    float *iqData;
    int iqCount;
    int purge;
    int dataRemaining;
    int sampleLoss;
    int sec;
    int milli;
} saIQPacket;
```

And the function that I end up calling:

```
SA_API saStatus saGetIQData(int device, saIQPacket *pkt);
```

In python, I have created a class as follows:

```
class IQPacketData (ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('iqData',ct.c_float*48611),
                ('iqCount',ct.c_int),
                ('purge', ct.c_int),
                ('dataRemaining', ct.c_int),
                ('sampleLoss', ct.c_int),
                ('sec', ct.c_int),
                ('milli', ct.c_int)]
```

I then use the above as follows:

```
self.iqPurge = ct.c_int(0)
self.iqDataRemaining = ct.c_int(0)
self.iqSampleLoss = ct.c_int(0)
self.secondsRemaining = ct.c_int(0)
self.millisecondsRemaining = ct.c_int(0)
self.iqarraySize = ct.c_int(24305)
self.iqArr = (ct.c_float*48611)()

self.saIQPacketData = IQPacketData(self.iqArr,
                        self.iqarraySize,
                        self.iqPurge,
                        self.iqDataRemaining,
                        self.iqSampleLoss,
                        self.secondsRemaining,
                        self.millisecondsRemaining)
```

After initializing the device, I call the function as follows:

```
err = self.dll.saGetIQData(self.deviceHandle,ct.pointer(self.saIQPacketData))
```

When the function runs, it returns a value of -1 which translates as a null pointer error.  Is there something wrong with the way I am constructing the struct and passing it in to the function call?

Comment: `iqData` is supposed to be a `float *`, not an array. Change it to `ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)`. You can still assign an array to the field. ctypes is smart enough to verify that the array element type is correct and stores the address in the struct field while keeping a reference to the underlying array in the struct's `_objects`.

Comment: There's no need to manually wrap the integer values as `c_int` instances. Also, the call can use `ct.byref(self.saIQPacketData)` instead of allocating a pointer.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun.  changing the type of iqData and passing a pointer in to the constructor fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @eryksun in the comments, the issue was of type.  Working code below for future reference:

The struct should be:

```
import ctypes as ct

class IQPacketData (ct.Structure):
_fields_ = [('iqData',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)),
            ('iqCount',ct.c_int),
            ('purge', ct.c_int),
            ('dataRemaining', ct.c_int),
            ('sampleLoss', ct.c_int),
            ('sec', ct.c_int),
            ('milli', ct.c_int)]
```

Creating the instance:

```
self.iqPurge = ct.c_int(0)
self.iqDataRemaining = ct.c_int(0)
self.iqSampleLoss = ct.c_int(0)
self.secondsRemaining = ct.c_int(0)
self.millisecondsRemaining = ct.c_int(0)
self.iqarraySize = ct.c_int(24305)
self.iqArr = (ct.c_float*48611)()
self.saIQPacketData = IQPacketData(self.iqArr,
                                   self.iqarraySize,
                                   self.iqPurge,
                                   self.iqDataRemaining,
                                   self.iqSampleLoss,
                                   self.secondsRemaining,
                                   self.millisecondsRemaining)
```

And finally calling the function:

```
err = self.dll.saGetIQData(self.deviceHandle,ct.pointer(self.saIQPacketData))
```

Some notes:  The array size parameter is half of the actual array size.  The function places 2 interleaving floats into the array for each sample (complex IQ Data).

Converting the array pointer back to a python array is done using Numpy:

```
np.fromiter(self.iqArr,dtype=np.float,count=48611)
```

Comment: It would be faster to use `np.frombuffer(self.iqArr, dtype=np.float32)`, but even faster to use the NumPy array directly, e.g. `self.iqArr = np.zeros((48611,), dtype=np.float32);` `self.saIQPacketData = IQPacketData(self.iqArr.ctypes.data_as(ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ...)`.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun, I will give that a go.